# "We plan" versus "we are planning"

Tags: grammaticality, present-tense, present-continuous

Is there a semantic difference between the following two sentences?

> In the future, we are planning to migrate our tool to the Z3 solver.

> In the future, we plan to migrate our tool to the Z3 solver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, their meanings are the same but there is a slight difference in use.

1)
A fixed arrangement in the near future is very often expressed by the **present continuous tense**:

> In the future, we are planning to migrate our tool to the Z3 solver.

The time expression: **in the future** informs us of *when* the action will occur. You can substitute those words with any adverb such as: `tomorrow`, `next week`, `in January` etc.. 
We often use the present continuous tense when we are talking about appointments, dates, plans and programmes. think of it as being an event which we have "pencilled" in our diary or calendar. Note that the time must be mentioned otherwise the reader or listener may confuse the future meaning with the present.

2) The **simple present** is also used for a definite future arrangement.

> In the future, we plan to migrate our tool to the Z3 solver.

However, it is more impersonal and formal than the continuous. Compare the following sentences:

> **I'm leaving tonight** = implies it is my decision, I have made the
>   arrangements myself.

and

> **I leave tonight** = could imply that the decision was not made by me but by my company or the manager I work for.

So back to your original question, may I suggest that the second sentence in the simple present tense i.e.`In the future, we plan to migrate our tool to the Z3 solver` **is preferred** and would sound more natural coming from an enterprise/company/business source.

Comment: In support of [Plain English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_English), I'd have to say the **preferred** option would be to just delete *"In the future"*. If they ever come to fruition, plans always involve things that (you hope) will happen ***in the future***, so arguably it's just pointless verbiage.

Comment: @FumbleFingers You're absolutely right and the phrase would become more believable, too! But that's my humble opinion, (I don't want to be responsible for anyone thinking that the expression: *"in the future"* is best avoided.)

Comment: *I'm leaving tonight* does not at all imply that it was the speaker's decision: "They're sending me to prison; I'm leaving tonight." That sentence is perfectly valid, and going to prison is clearly not something the speaker wants to do.

Comment: "I'm writing a letter of complaint tomorrow morning." Implies the speaker's will, intention and decision. Besides, I did not say that the present continuous when expressing a future event **always** implies personal intention but it *can* do.

Comment: @WendiKidd "That sentence is perfectly valid, ..." Who said, it wasn't? Both sentences have the same meaning but there is a *slight* difference. No one is being forced to use one or the other phrase, they're practically interchangeable.

Comment: @ Mari-Lou: I've upvoted the answer, but (like WendiKidd, I assume) I see no justification whatsoever for the idea that the choice between *I'm leaving* and *I leave* has anything to do with volition. There's not even a *slight* difference on that front.

Comment: @FumbleFingers would you agree that "I leave tonight" sounds more impersonal, likewise: "In the future, we plan to migrate our tool to Z3 solver." I have consulted two grammar books: Advanced Language Practice by Michael Vince and A practical English Grammar by A.J.Thomson and A.V. Martinet (4th edition) and they claim that the present tense **can also** be used to: "*describe fixed events which are not simply the wishes of the speaker.*"

Comment: @ Mari-Lou: *I leave tonight* only sounds more "impersonal" because it's a stilted/dated/formal tense choice for that particular verb in that particular context. I'd need to see the full context of your grammar books to give an opinion on that one. I'm sure it doesn't reflect anything that could reasonably be classed as even a "slight nuance" in the vast majority of usages, but maybe they've identified contexts where a nuance does credibly exist.

Comment: It is nevertheless an interesting topic and it is a shame that we (it happens to me as well) feel the need to be defensive. After all, it's only words. I only wanted to point out a slightly different interpretation, which I had studied and learnt myself.

Comment: @ Mari-Lou: There's variation across different users' cultures and personal characters, but I don't think you should make too much of the "defensive/adversarial" nature of some "debates" in comments on ELU. I disagree about that "volition" nuance being relevant in this exact context, but I'm quite sure there are *other* contexts where something along those lines applies. You could reasonably say, for example, *Venus aligns with the Sun next Monday*, but I'm far less happy with *Venus is aligning with the Sun next Monday* (I'd much prefer ***will be** aligning* with the "continuous" aspect).

Answer (score 3):

There is really no semantic difference between the two sentences.